# Is it possible to create a non-ecommerce site using Magento?

Tags: discount, coupon, coupon-codes, promotions, promotional-banner

I have a site to develop that needs to be a kind of voucher code site. This means that the site will provide voucher codes for other sites, the user will come to my site and pick voucher codes for another site and will then redirect to the target site. In short, it does not need any Add-to-Cart functionality of magento.

> An example site is shown below in link: https://www.promothecode.com/coupon/chiquito

However, the site I plan to create requires a strong Admin side for Support, so I believe Magento has a strong Admin interface and that is the reason why I am planning to choose Magento for my site. So my questions are:

1. Is it good to use magento for developing such non e-commerce sites
2. What are the best practices that should take care of when developing such sites using magento

Please share your thoughts... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build non-commercial website then you have to use different framework (like word-press,Joomla,Drupal), because Magento is specially designed for E-commerce based website builder platform right.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible?" and "is it worth it?" are 2 different things.
But let's take them one by one:

**Is it possible?**
Yes. It certainly is.
I've done this in magento 1 using Colin Mollenhour's Magento Lite: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite

For magento 2 is a little more difficult because of all the dependency checks and the circular module dependencies. SO you cannot remove some modules without removing the full circle of dependencies.
I did a presentation in 2016 about exactly this... stripping down all the modules you don't need so you end up with only the framework and CMS functionality and build on top of that. It may be outdated because magento changed a lot since then, but it may help you if you decide to start on this adventure: https://github.com/tzyganu/MageTitansIt2016/blob/master/Magento-2-as-a-CMS.pdf.

**Is it worth it?**

My personal opinion is NO.

- Magento was designed to work for e-commerce websites and it centers around the products and categories.
- You will have some (if not a lot) of troubles removing unnecessary modules from magento to make the code cleaner.
- If you don't want to clean it up and decide to use it like it is and just hide from frontend and backend the links to modules you don't need you will end up with useless code that only adds overhead to the performance.
- Magento 2 does not play well with a shared host. You may decide that your website is simple enough and does not require a dedicated hosing that may cost way more than a shared one.
- you will have to do your custom entities "the magento way" when in practice you may not actually need it.